# Proving a function to be continuous in Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying exercises of section 1.7 of C. Wayne Patty and I am unable to think about solution of this question.

> Note that I want to ask b part only.

> [image]

My attempt -> The definition of continuity is inverse of the definition of open sets given here. So, I don't know how defination of continuity can be derived from definition of open sets here ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $Y$. You want to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$. But, *by the definition of the topology on* $X$, this is true indeed, since $A\in\mathcal T$ if and only if $A=f^{-1}(B)$ for some $B\in\mathcal U$.